# Is it not possible to start an activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I want to call this activity from a  class extending BroadcastReceiver but its not working

```
Intent i = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Is it not possible to start an activity from BroadcastReceiver. Please help.

Comment: What erro are you getting? What Android version are you testing on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, yourclass.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

yourclass.class is your activity class that you want to start. Also, do not forget to add flags as new task.

Answer (score 1):

Add the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) flag to your intent, eg:

```
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```