# Open Browser from a button click on Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, broadcastreceiver

I tried to open the browser from a button click on a widget. I used a `BroadcastReceiver`, where from `onReceiver()` I want to open a browser.

I got error like:

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it not possible to start an activity from BroadcastReceiver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949746/is-it-not-possible-to-start-an-activity-from-broadcastreceiver)

Comment: Did you set a PendingIntent on your button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start and activity form an invisible component like a `BroadcaseReceiver`, you need to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. This is what error says. Here is a possible solution.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(<Your action here>);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Alternatively you can show a Notification first. This will just put a message in status bar and won't not interrupt current user's activity (e.g. gaming). Later, when user have time he or she can click on this notification, and then browser will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps--->

```
Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

String text ="Visit <a href=\"http://manning.com/\">Manning home page</a>";

Button1.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
Button1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score -2):

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.xxxx);
button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener){

public void onClick(){

String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);

}
}
```

Comment: Your answer would work if this was done in an Activity, but it's a widget which uses AppWidgetProvider instead.